# unity Ensure Read/Write is enabled

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I new to Unity.

Can some one tell me what this error mean

```
Ensure Read/Write is enabled on the Particle System's Texture
```

[image]

Particle system need to play on start but sometimes work(play effect) sometimes not.
Thanks

Comment: Di you create a material for the particlesystem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Error because your image has not been marked as enabled

Here's how to fix it

[image: example image]

Hope you will fix your mistake

Comment: Your answer solved this for me. I realise that this is an old question, but can anyone elaborate on why a particle system would need read/write access to the image?

Comment: This is the correct answer, solved the problem for me too!

Answer (score 11):

I've got the same error, but with a different reason, so I'd like to share to help others that can get stuck in the same situation:

**Cause**

1. I was using a Cone shape for particle emission (Shape tab)
2. By my own mistake, I selected Texture Default-ParticleSystem
3. I don't know exactly why, but these Unity Default textures always cause the discussed error
4. In this case it's tricky to find, because Unity doesn't clearly tell which texture is wrongly set (from the Render tab or from the Shape tab).

[image: Example of wrong particle setting]

**Solution**

1. I've just removed the Shape Texture setting it to "None" then the error disappeared

Comment: In my Unity it's happening, I don't know the reason or if it happens on other machines, but in my Unity 2019.2.3f1 I'm having to use my own textures instead of the default particle texture.